# MongoDB How to write query for checking array of values for time intervals greater than and less than time

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have table name users, and I want to get the users between some
time intervals.

My users table

```
user_id,updated_at
    1        100
    2        200
    3        300
    4        400   
    5        500 
    6        600
    7        700
```

Normal query for checking time of greater than and less than is below:

```
db.users.find({"updated_at":{$gt:90,$lte:200}})
```

I have map of timestamp for this

```
Map<Long,Long> timestamp: which contains values for greater than and less than time.
```

Now If I pass values in map like

```
timetampMap.put(90,200)
timetampMap.put(350,400)
timetampMap.put(560,700)
```

The output should be after query

```
select * from users where (updated_at>90 && updated_at<=200)
select * from users where (updated_at>350 && updated_at<=400)
select * from users where (updated_at>560 && updated_at<=700)

user_id,updated_at
1        100
2        200
4        400   
6        600
7        700
```

Please help to write query according to the above requirement, I don't want to use for loop for this in code.

Comment: Can you please post your collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$or` operator something like `db.users.find({ $or: [ { updated_at:{ $gt:90, $lte:200}}, { updated_at:{ $gt:350, $lte:400}}, { updated_at:{ $gt:560, $lte:700}} ] })`

This query is doing or for your different ranges.

You can read more about it here https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Comment: It depends on which library you are using for mongo interaction